# inputenc, Sanskrit/Pali, transliteration and utf8 4-byte encoding

Tags: unicode, input-encodings, transliteration

For a Dharma playing card project I created a database (charset utf8mb4) that stores (among other things) Pali/Sanskrit terms and their transliteration.

The goal is to have an easy web interface to enter data -- including copy/paste from other websites -- that can create pdf files via *tex automatically.

I succeeded to make automatic cards including transliteration but I fail with Sanskrit.

- What would you recommend for such an environment?
- How can I make the Sanskrit/Pali work?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[parskip,a4, landscape,twocolumn ]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}

%\usepackage[combine]{ucs}   
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

minimal example ...

Sanskrit: ... {fails}

transliteration: samyak-dṛṣṭi

\end{document}
```

Comment: you will get better sanskrit typestting with xelatex or luahblatex, are you committed to using pdftex? Pdflatex is restricted to 256-character fonts and knows nothing about the font shaping required in such scripts

Comment: Just installed the xetex package. It works out of the box!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will get better sanskrit typestting with xelatex or luahblatex, are you committed to using pdftex? Pdflatex is restricted to 256-character fonts and knows nothing about the font shaping required in such scripts